# HTML module loading

Tags: html, w3c

While developing one of my html app, my main html file go big in length. Is there any way  to split my codes in separate module and merge them in my main html page. Please don't suggest iframe. I don't want make it as separate page (with another HTML and Body tags).

My design is like this.

**Current:**

***index.html***

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div id="sidebar">
          ..........
       </div>

       <div id="content-top">
         <div id="ct-list">
            ...........
         </div>
            ...........
       </div>

       <div id="content-bottom">
            ............
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What i am expecting**

***index.html***

```
<html>
    <body>
        <Module src="sidebar.html">
        <Module src="content-top.html">
        <Module src="content-bottom.html">     
    </body>
</html>
```

***sidebar.html***

```
<div id="sidebar">
    ..........
</div>
```

***content-top.html***

```
<div id="content-top">
    <Module src="ct-list.html"> 
    ...........
</div>
```

***ct-list.html***

```
<div id="ct-list">
    ...........
</div>
```

***content-bottom.html***

```
<div id="content-bottom">
    ............
</div>
```

Comment: What benefits are you expecting to derive from this?  If you want smaller files to edit keep them separate and have a build process which combines them back into one file before you upload to the server.  There's no need to make every visitor to your site repeat this work.

Comment: if i have 5000 lines of code in index.html. it is good to have them in separate modules. tough to maintain all those lines in single file.

Comment: Yes, but your users don't have to maintain, they just have to use it.  You're the one that has to maintain it, do it before you upload.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few options to do this, frames is one which doesn't require you learn anything in addition to HTML/CSS

Second option though many will laugh at it would be .shtml, it's a simple server side system to do exactly what you want without needing to learn much beyond the HTML/CSS
`<!--#include file="sidebar.shtml"-->`

From there are many options, PHP, asp.net, Ruby, Python etc etc however all these options come with a learning curve which might not be worthwhile if you only ever intend to make this page and that's all

Comment: Thansk for replying..no i don't want it to do with server side scripting. i just like to know is there any option similar to my concept?

Comment: Umm, there's probably no way to do it without some kind of serverside scripting.  Well.. unless you count building the page using AJAX as a valid option

Comment: i know jQuerymobile has this concept. But they treated each module as separate page.

Comment: OK yeah... so jQuery is a client side scripting library.  So you'd be doing the same thing except having the client make multiple requests to build the page.  For what it's worth shtml would be much easier than doing that

Comment: will it (shtml) run in by all servers?

Comment: Not necessarily, and these days it's probably not enabled by default.  That's going to be a problem with introducing any kind of logic to a site, well, unless you do go ahead with client side.  I mean... if you really must do it that way sure it'll cost a little time in page load and bandwidth but if you just can't have any kind of serverside logic then maybe it's your only option

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15598/discussion-between-user10-and-ben-stephens)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really popular tool for this in html itself. Probably you should use some simple script on the server side which will combine it together. Or you can use JavaScript and Ajax.

Comment: @Ben Stephens, suggest me to use $(document).load("sidebar.html") in jquery. which i feel good option.